# excel4node with React , how to create the file without having to save it?

Tags: reactjs, download, excel4node

In excel4node I can create a file using write or I can write to buffer as follows:

> wb.writeToBuffer().then(function (buffer) {
>
> // Do something with buffer
>
> });

How I can take the buffer and then make React download a file to the Browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

excel4node did not work with React.

It seems that only works on nodejs server side.

I ended up using https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx